# how to add variables to joomla urls?

Tags: joomla2.5

I am creting joomla component. In admin part main page shows users list. By click on toolbar icon for each user i want to show some list of information from my tables. By clicking at list element or toolbar menu i want to open from with fields for editing info from the list.

How can i transfer user ID from list of users to list of info and to the edit form (then adding new list elem, id of current user must be saved in the table with other data)?
Withowt joomla i can use some variable like selected_user_id in uri's, by what is the right way in joomla?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use standard html link, where you will put userId in GET variable. 
In Joomla you have JRequest class (http://docs.joomla.org/JRequest/11.1). You can use one of  it's methods to get (getVar(), getInt() or getString()) or set variable (set()).

Comment: But how can i put userid in link generated by toolbar icons?